# Degree of freedom in t.test()

Tags: r, data-mining

I used the t.test() function to calculate the t test of the following:

```
t.test(iris$Petal.Width[iris$Species == "setosa"],
       iris$Petal.Width[iris$Species == "versicolor"])
```

There are 150 rows (100 for versicolor and 50 for setosa).

The degree of freedom here when i check the output of the t-test is 74.755. I wanted to know how this value is obtained since I wanted to implement the t-test manually. I managed to get the t-statistic correctly but I would like to get the p-value as well. For my p-value I used df as 148 (n-2). And it is not getting same result as t.test().

Comment: Take a look at `stats:::t.test.default` - the line starting `if (var.equal) {` - then the part after `else {` will give you the code for the `df` calculation. Keep scrolling down and you will get the pval calculation too.

Comment: also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test

Comment: Where did ypu get the idea that there were 100 rows with `iris$Species == "versicolor"`

Comment: table(iris$Species) -> (50,50,50)